# How can I create an iframe button to embed into a website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a local site for a bit of a side project I am doing in rails.

I am creating a site that basically opens a modal popup and displays some data about the site its currently on. So the title of the site and meta description thats it.

I am wondering how easy it would be to create an iframe that is my site above but I can put on another test site that I have set up to test some functionality?

I am using mechanize in rails to get the data and thats easy but I am wondering how anyone goes about creating an embedded button on a site?

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Lets start my custom gem pile here:

gem 'mechanize', '2.7.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code on button click for create iframe

```
$('#button').click(function() {
if($('#myIframe').size() == 0) {
    $('<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>');
}
```

});